# How to get QJsonObject values in order?

Tags: c++, json, qt

I want to use Json in Qt and my data inside the `QJsonObject` must be in some particular order since we have some confirmation method via a token and getting a hash of the Json.

Since `QJsonObject` sorts its key-value pairs in alphabetical order I something like this to happen:

```
QJsonObject object;
object.insert("B","b");
object.insert("A","a");
qDebug() << QJsonDocument(object).toJson(); // this-line
```

I want **this-line** to printout something like this:

```
{"B":"b","A":"a"}
```

but instead i get this:

```
{
    "A":"a",
    "B":"b"
}
```

I have written a class:

**jsonobject.h**

```
class JsonObject
{
public:
    JsonObject();
    void insert(QString key,QJsonValue value);
    void remove(QString key);
    QString toJsonString();
    QString convertQJsonValue2String(QJsonValue value);
    QString convertQJsonArray2String(QJsonArray array);
    QString convertQJsonObject2String(QJsonObject object);
private:
    void appendKey(QString key,QString * out);
    QJsonObject qJsonObject;
    QStringList keysInOrder;
};
```

**jsonobject.cpp**

```
#include "jsonobject.h"

JsonObject::JsonObject()
{
    keysInOrder.clear();
}

void JsonObject::insert(QString key, QJsonValue value)
{
    if(!keysInOrder.contains(key))
        keysInOrder.append(key);
    qJsonObject.insert(key,value);
}

void JsonObject::remove(QString key)
{
    keysInOrder.removeOne(key);
qJsonObject.remove(key);
}

QString JsonObject::toJsonString()
{
    QString out;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < keysInOrder.size() ; i++)
    {
        appendKey(keysInOrder[i],&out);
        out.append(convertQJsonValue2String(qJsonObject.value(keysInOrder[i])));
        if(i != (keysInOrder.size() - 1))
            out.append(",");
    }
    return out.prepend("{").append("}");
}

QString JsonObject::convertQJsonObject2String(QJsonObject object)
{
    QStringList keys = object.keys();
    QString out;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < keys.size() ; i++)
    {
        appendKey(keys[i],&out);
        out.append(convertQJsonValue2String(object[keys[i]]));
        if(i != keys.size() - 1)
            out.append(",");
    }
    return out.prepend("{").append("}");
}

void JsonObject::appendKey(QString key, QString *out)
{
    out->append("\"");
    out->append(key);
    out->append("\"");
    out->append(":");
}

QString JsonObject::convertQJsonValue2String(QJsonValue value)
{
    switch(value.type())
    {
    case QJsonValue::Null:
        return QString("null");
        break;
    case QJsonValue::Bool:
        return QString("%1").arg(value.toBool());
        break;
    case QJsonValue::Double:
        return QString("%1").arg(value.toDouble());
        break;
    case QJsonValue::String:
        return value.toString().prepend("\"").append("\"");
        break;
    case QJsonValue::Object:
        return convertQJsonObject2String(value.toObject());
        break;
    case QJsonValue::Array:
        return convertQJsonArray2String(value.toArray());
        break;
    case QJsonValue::Undefined:
        return QString();
        break;
    }
    return QString();
}

QString JsonObject::convertQJsonArray2String(QJsonArray array)
{
    QString out;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.size() ; i++)
    {
        QJsonValue value = array.at(i);
        out.append(convertQJsonValue2String(value));
        if(i != (array.size() - 1))
            out.append(",");
    }
    return out.prepend("[").append("]");
}
```

the problem here is that I have `QJsonObject`s inside and my `converQJSonObject2String(QJsonObject object)` still don't have that order.

Comment: Doesn't convertQJsonObject2String() need to loop through the keys in reverse order since object.keys() returns the keys in order?

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like you're trying to use json for something it is not meant to do. Json does not have a canonical representation, so even if you manage to order the keys correctly, you might still run into problems. (Keys with non-ascii characters, whitespace differences, ...)

While it is certainly possible to do what you're looking for (I suggest using another library that offers this possibility), try to take a step back and think about what you're trying to achieve.

Would it be possible to take the hash of the json you receive from the server directly?

Comment: @mostafaTmj: Great! You sohuld write an answer to your own question so other people with the same problem can find your solution.